# How do I actually store the randomly chosen word as a word?

Tags: c#, random

So I am working on a hangman program. It will pull from a list of 126 different words and randomly select one of the words. It will also output an "_" for each character.

But now, when I'm trying to determine the 'correct guess' of the word, I can't figure out how to actually store the value of the randomly chosen word. Sounds funny, but what have you. lol.

```
String[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt");
        Random randomWord = new Random();
        //int lineCount = File.ReadLines("WordList.txt").Count();            
        int activeWord = randomWord.Next(0, myWordArrays.Length);
        string userSelection = "";

        Console.WriteLine("Are you Ready to play Hangman? yes/no: ");

        userSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            if(userSelection == "yes")
            {

                foreach(char letter in myWordArrays[activeWord])
                {

                    //the console.write(activeword) only shows the line number o.0. 
                    //when I try to print out .Write(myWordArrays) it shows a 
                    //System.(something) on the screen. ugh.

                    Console.Write(activeWord);
                    Console.Write("_ ");

                }
```

I believe this is all the code that needs to be referenced as it is really the only code that deals with the choosing of the random word. I'm truly baffled by this. I've tried to set different things to the active word and I can't think of any logical way to have the 'foreach' also place each letter into an array (which would be beneficial later when I'm ready to search for each letter when the user guesses the letter).

Comment: activeWord is an INDEX into your `myWordArrays`. if you want to print out the word, not its index, then it should be `console.write(myWordArrays[activeWord])`

Comment: Not clear what's the problem, but few observations. The `activeWord` is actually `activeWordIndex`, `activeWord = myWordArrays[activeWordIndex]` and you can print `activeWord` which is a `string`

Comment: @MarcB THANK YOU -- but my goodness. I SWORE I tried that before and it kept throwing an error. But, it's writing it now. 

So can I create a variable and set it equal to  myWordArrays[activeWord]? I'll try it, but hopefully I can. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @AD.Net - Thank you, but if I try doing

'Console.WriteLine(activeWord); it only prints the line number. So maybe I'll try setting a variable = myWordArrays[activeWord] in order to more easily call that word! I'm gonna' try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the line that says

```
int activeWord = randomWord.Next(0, myWordArrays.Length);
```

change it to

```
String activeWord = myWordArrays[randomWord.Next(0, myWordArrays.Length)];
```

and change the foreach to

```
foreach(char letter in activeWord)
```

and you don't need to have the foreach put the word into a char array.  When you need a char array, you can just say

```
activeWord.toCharArray()
```

But you probably won't even need that as String is IEnumerable, which means that you can do a foreach on a String, without turning it into an array, just like I did above.

Comment: I tried activeword as a String the first time, but it throws an error "cannot implicitly convert type int to string." - I assumed it was because the usage of randomWord (as a Random datatype?) automatically makes it an int?

Comment: If you were trying to store the random number into the String, then you would have got that error.  But if you take an item from myWordArrays to store into it, you get no error because the items in myWordArrays are strings.  You have to be clear on this:  randomWord.Next(0,myWordArrays.Length) just gives you a random **number** between 0 and 126 (the length of myWordArrays).  It does **not** give you the actual word at that index in the array.  For that, you have to do myWordArrays[randomWord.Next(0,myWordArrays.Length)].

Comment: AHHH. I think I see why. The version I used is simply randomizing a number between 0 and 126 because of its syntax being completely outside of the actual array of 'mywordarrays'. By placing the randomizer into the array delegation (maybe I misused that term here) it selects a random word and immediately places it into the array, because that's where I initialized that process. Is that right?

Comment: You might be confusing what the Random class does.  Just because you called your Random object by the name of randomWord, does not mean that it is going to give you a string.  randomWord is a Random type of object - a random number generator.  So randomWord.Next(a,b) is just going to give you a random number between a and b.

Comment: You did misuse terms.  You are placing the randomizer into the array **index** to select the word that is already in that array, at that index.  Because the index is random, you get a random word out of your array of words.

Comment: No, I understand its functionality (even though I may not understand how it chooses its number). But I DO understand the difference between what I did and what you did and I'm pretty sure I understand why yours is string allowable and mine is not. Because in my case, I set activeWord equal to merely a number whereas you put activeWord = to whatever word is indexed into the myWordArrays by the randomWord.Next().

Comment: I have selected this as the best answer because not only did it put me in the right direction, but I learned something very important!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
// Read the lines (words) from a file and store them in a list
String[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt");

// Generate a random number and select the word at that index of the list myWordArrays
Random randomWord = new Random();            
int activeWord = randomWord.Next(0, myWordArrays.Length);
string randomlyChosenWord = myWordArrays[activeword];

// Query the user
Console.WriteLine("Are you Ready to play Hangman? yes/no: ");
string userSelection = Console.ReadLine();

// Initialize
if(userSelection == "yes")
{
    foreach(char letter in randomlyChosenWord)
    {
       Console.Write("_ ");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, Joshua! I actually just posted my own answer to my own question (just below this) and I chose 'answerWord' as my variable instead of 'randomlyChosenWord'. LOL. Thank you so much. 

But, above this, someone else suggested placing the randomizer into the array portion itself so that it grabs random word between lines 0 and myWordArrays.Length and places it right into the array. So I guess that would remove the necessity of having to create another variable. Very nice. Thank you for this, Josh!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone, especially Marc B. Here is the solution that fixed it. Granted, it currently prints the random word as many times as there are chars in the word, but I'll fix that in a minute.

If you can see a more efficient manner of doing this, feel free to let me know!

```
private static void printWord()
    {
        String[] myWordArrays = File.ReadAllLines("WordList.txt");
        Random randomWord = new Random();
        //int lineCount = File.ReadLines("WordList.txt").Count();            
        int activeWord = randomWord.Next(0, myWordArrays.Length);
        string userSelection = "";
        string answerWord = myWordArrays[activeWord];

        Console.WriteLine("Are you Ready to play Hangman? yes/no: ");

        userSelection = Console.ReadLine();
            if(userSelection == "yes")
            {
                //This runs through the randomly chosen word and prints an underscore in place of each letter - it does work
                foreach(char letter in myWordArrays[activeWord])
                {
                    Console.Write(answerWord);
                    Console.Write("_ ");

                }

                //This prints to the console "Can you guess what this 'varyingLength' letter word is?" - it does work.

            }
```